# Names removed from Mac Mail VIP list are sent to Junk

Tags: mail.app, email, spam

I do not use the VIP list in my Mac Mail (Version 12.2). It's just not how I organize my mail — not how I roll.

And yet somehow, I accidentally added my wife to the VIP list.

It was very easy to remove her name from the VIP list, and in fact the extraneous "VIP" list is no longer even present in my list of mailboxes. Great.

But now we get to the problem.

When she was removed from the VIP list, she was somehow added to the Junk list. Every email that I receive from her – from either of her three email accounts – is unceremoniously dumped into Junk Mail. This did not happen before the VIP incident, and I can't seem to "re-approve" her contact as a valid and good email now.

**How can I remove my wife from Junk Mail? Please help, and in addition to my sanity, you may save a marriage!**

Here are some details:

- The VIP addition/subtraction was the very clear and distinct moment that this happened
- POP3
- I've bashed BASH many times, and am not afraid of
  Terminal
- In addition to Apple's junk filters, I use a general rule to send any email that is not in my contacts straight to Junk
- My wife is in my contacts

Let me know if I can provide any more specific information.

Comment: I don't use the defaul Mail application but can't you highlight or click on the name and select 'not junk' or something similar?  You might need to 'reset' your junk mail filter rules, too.  Also, is your wife in the Contacts app with this same email address (not just the name)?

Comment: @fsb The "not junk" can be done from the junk mail folder, but does not correct this issue. Resetting the junk rules sounds like a bit of a hell, losing 10 years of the system's learning. I would rather edit one small line of code, if that is possible. She is in the contacts — like I said, this worked perfectly before the VIP debacle. These are all good things to check. Sadly though, I've checked them already. Any thoughts on editing the junk mail "history"?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "she's in the contacts" you mean she's there **with the exact same email address** that's being put in Junk?

Comment: @fsb Yes, she's there with the exact same email address that's being put in Junk. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: @Parapluie Can you try to make a rule in the mail app to send all those messages  to inbox and see if it works fine?

Comment: Also, Go to mail preferences -> junk mail-> tick perform custom actions and hit advanced. You should see some conditions. Try to do something that defies all those rules.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Thank you; however, the Junk rules seem un-defiable. I have added the rules as you suggest, and carefully ordered them to _follow_ the junk sort. Whatever VIP-removing action so vilified my poor dear wife, seems to be really, really bad, in Apple's eyes.

Comment: You should untick the last line the junk settings, Filter junk mail before applying my rules. and see if the problem continues. You should add her mail to Previous Recipients.You can check the same in Window-> Previous Recipients.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Yes. Done and done and no luck. I believe that this is a non-standard issue, related specifically to some action of the "VIP" list. Right now, I am looking for blacklist files in my system library that may be related.